# Network accessible screen

Tags: networking, wifi, hardware, screen

Using Raspi, does anyone know of a way to take an old desktop monitor and make it network accessible from any pc? The idea being that you could access it much in the same way you might access Bluetooth speakers, or an Apple TV? I want to be able to put my laptop on my desk, and be able to link it up through the wireless to my screen, or do the same with an iPad or other device.

Comment: I've heard of wireless HDMI connectors for doing this sort of thing. I'm not sure if this is really feasible with the Pi. Either way your question is too broad for the Q&A format of the site. Try doing some research and have a go at rewording the question so it is more specific.